# N2 CMS Is it possible to add a part to non-cms Page

Tags: n2cms, n2

I am using N2 in asp.net mvc. Is it possible to add a part to a dropable zone defined in a non-n2cms page?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. DroppableZones are handled as part of content items. While it -- in theory -- is possible to modify or use the N2CMS code to add a droppable zone to a non-n2cms page, this functionality isn't provided for or supported by n2cms itself.